# Export selected rows and columns to CSV-file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to export a selected range of cells to a .csv file using VBA. What I have come up with so far does the job excellently for cohering selections, but fails misearably when multiple columns are selected.

Here is the code I managed to put together from snippets found on the internet: It also fiddles around with some UI and since my Excel speaks German and I need to have "." as decimal separator instead of "," it tweaks that.

```
Sub Range_Nach_CSV_()
Dim vntFileName As Variant
Dim lngFN As Long
Dim rngRow As Excel.Range
Dim rngCell As Excel.Range
Dim strDelimiter As String
Dim strText As String
Dim strTextCell As String
Dim strTextCelll As String
Dim bolErsteSpalte As Boolean
Dim rngColumn As Excel.Range
Dim wksQuelle As Excel.Worksheet
Dim continue As Boolean

strDelimiter = vbtab

continue = True

Do While continue = True

vntFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Test.txt", _
    FileFilter:="TXT-File (*.TXT),*.txt")
If vntFileName = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Dir(vntFileName)) > 0 Then
    Dim ans As Integer
    ans = MsgBox("Datei existiert bereits. Überschreiben?", vbYesNo)
    If ans = vbYes Then
        continue = False
    ElseIf ans = vbNo Then
        continue = True
    Else
        continue = False
    End If
Else
    continue = False
End If

Loop

Set wksQuelle = ActiveSheet

lngFN = FreeFile
Open vntFileName For Output As lngFN

    For Each rngRow In Selection.Rows
        strText = ""
        bolErsteSpalte = True

        For Each rngCell In rngRow.Columns
            strTextCelll = rngCell.Text
            strTextCell = Replace(strTextCelll, ",", ".")
            If bolErsteSpalte Then
                strText = strTextCell
                bolErsteSpalte = False
            Else
                strText = strText & strDelimiter & strTextCell
            End If
        Next

    Print #lngFN, strText

    Next
Close lngFN

End Sub
```

As I already mentioned the sub works well with coherent selections and also with multiple selected lines, but fails when it comes to multiple columns.

The current output of the sub can be seen on this here picture:
[multiple columns failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05CMG.jpg)

As one would expect, I want the .csv-file (or respective .txt-file) to look like this:
[multiple columns desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcxWC.jpg)

How can I achieve the desired behaviour for the last case?
And would someone be so kind to include the links as images? If perceived appropriate, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might seem a little complex, but your use case isn't very simple...

It does assume that each of the selected areas is the same size, and that they all line up (as either rows or columns)

```
Sub Tester()

Dim s As String, srow As String, sep As String
Dim a1 As Range, rw As Range, c As Range, rCount As Long
Dim areaCount As Long, x As Long
Dim bColumnsSelected As Boolean
Dim sel As Range

    bColumnsSelected = False
    Set sel = Selection

    areaCount = Selection.Areas.Count
    Set a1 = Selection.Areas(1)

    If areaCount > 1 Then
        If a1.Cells(1).Column <> Selection.Areas(2).Cells(1).Column Then
            'areas represent different columns (not different rows)
            bColumnsSelected = True
            Set sel = a1
        End If
    End If

    rCount = 0

    For Each rw In sel.Rows

        rCount = rCount + 1
        srow = ""
        sep = ""

        For Each c In rw.Cells
            srow = srow & sep & Replace(c.Text, ",", ".")
            sep = ","
        Next c

        'if there are multiple areas selected (as columns), then include those
        If bColumnsSelected Then
            For x = 2 To areaCount
                For Each c In Selection.Areas(x).Rows(rCount).Cells
                    srow = srow & sep & Replace(c.Text, ",", ".")
                Next c
            Next x
        End If

        s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, vbCrLf, "") & srow
    Next rw

    Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Works for non contiguous range as well :)